# If all objects have the same css value then

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking for a way, in jQuery, to check if all elements with the same class (.piece) has their z-index to 0 and if so then an alert is launched.
Here is what i did:

```
$(".piece").each(function(){  
    if($(this).css('z-index') != '0'){
        valide=false;  
    }else{
         valide = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: What's not working/your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 if($('.piece').length == $('.piece').filter(function() {return $(this).css('z-index') == 0;}).length){
    // all have z-index 0
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

getting the `z-index` value as you've tried, will return a value of `auto`. You can get the actual value with the zindex method: `.zIndex()`